# Do Horadric Caches drop all legendaries or only bounty-specific legendaries?

Tags: diablo-iii

There is a whole bunch of bounty-specific legendaries that only drop in Horadric Caches and for specific Acts in which you performed the bounties. I already got some of those bounty-specific legendaries, but no generic legendaries from the cubes so far.

Do Horadric Caches *only* drop these bounty-specific legendaries? Or can they drop any legendary in the game?

Comment: I'm not sure about the Cache's, but there's [a blue post about Kadala](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12248064907?page=2#23)

Comment: so far the only things I've seen coming out of the a1 bags is the mad monarch mace and ring of royal grandeurs.

Comment: I got a 'Coven's Criterion' shield out of a cache the other day

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From a blue post on the official Diablo 3 forum](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12373027360?page=4#63):

> To clarify: Horadric Caches can drop any type of Legendary (regular or Bounty-exclusive) EXCEPT those that require Torment difficulty on higher. As difficulty has no impact on Horadric Caches, this also includes the ability to drop Torment-only Legendaries. <s>Kadala is similar, as she also cannot generate Torment-only Legendaries.</s>
>
> Only the gear from monsters, including Rift Guardians, is affected by Difficulty level.

[From the 2.0.5 patch notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/patch-notes/2-0-5):

> Kadala - Can now drop Torment only Legendary items

Answer (score 4):

Caches can drop all legendaries.  I've gotten both cache only and standard legendaries (such as chantodos) from caches.  I've even gotten a legendary recipie or two.